# How can I align questions to the left in exam enviorment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

I am making a exam type questions, where I am struggling to align the text. These is my output: [image]

Where I am looking for the text to be aligned on the right side of the line I have drawn, and the questions be on the left with a separation of 1cm, the problem begins when I start when the number of the question is bigger than one digit. Latex is kind of new to me so I was wondering if someone could help me. 
My code is:

```
    \documentclass[20pt]{exam}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\huge \arabic{question}}



\everymath={\displaystyle}
\renewcommand*{\choicelabel}{\large \thechoice)}
\renewcommand*{\choicelabel}{ 
  \ifnum\value{choice}>1
    \makebox[4em][r]{\LARGE \thechoice)}
  \else
   \LARGE \thechoice)
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
% from exam.cls, line 4107:
\renewenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{15pt}%
       \def\choice{%
         \if@correctchoice
           \color@endgroup
           \endgroup
         \fi
         \item
         \do@choice@pageinfo
       } % choice
       \def\CorrectChoice{%
         \if@correctchoice
           \color@endgroup
           \endgroup
         \fi
         \ifprintanswers
           \ifhmode \unskip\unskip\unvbox\voidb@x \fi
           \begingroup \color@begingroup \@correctchoicetrue
           \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
         \fi
         \item
         \do@choice@pageinfo
       } % CorrectChoice
       \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
       \choiceshook
     }%
  }%
  {\if@correctchoice \color@endgroup \endgroup \fi \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\begin{questions}
\question Si $\mathlarger{a \in \mathbb{Z}^{-}}$ y $\mathlarger{b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$, ¿Cuál(es) de las siguientes expresiones \textbf{siempre} es(son) menor(es) que cero?

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*)]
\item $\mathlarger{a - b}$
\item $\mathlarger{a + b}$ 
\item $\mathlarger{a(a - b)}$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{choices}
\choice Solo I
\choice Solo II
\choice Solo III
\choice Solo I y III
\choice I, II y III
\end{choices}
\question
\question 
\question
\question
\question
\question
\question 
\question 
\question
\question
\question Si $\mathlarger{a \in \mathbb{Z}^{-}}$ y $\mathlarger{b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$, ¿Cuál(es) de las siguientes expresiones \textbf{siempre} es(son) menor(es) que cero?
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*)]
\item $\mathlarger{a - b}$
\item $\mathlarger{a + b}$ 
\item $\mathlarger{a(a - b)}$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{choices}
\choice Solo I
\choice Solo II
\choice Solo III
\choice Solo I y III
\choice I, II y III
\end{choices}

\end{questions}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please update your MWE adding the packages you are using, so that users can compile it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing your document preamble is difficult to help you. Help us to help you and extend your code snippet to complete small document.

Comment: Changing font size in labels is not good idea. It caused your problems.

Comment: But I need it to be of that size, is there any possible way of doing it?

Comment: So basically you need to move the enumerate to the right at least 4em (the width of \choicelabel).  Try [left=4em].